# Inconsistent behaviour using string with superscript as label

Tags: plotting, string-manipulation, input, legending

This might be a silly question, but actually I lost a bit of time to figure out what I was doing wrong and now I want to understand better.
Moreover, I'm not sure if the behaviour I see is a bug or not.

I was experimenting with the "new" [PlotLabels](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLabels.html) functionality and I created a label which is a string with a superscript, i.e. I naively employed the usual superscript notation (ctrl+6) inside quotation marks. This is what I usually do for labels, copy-pasting the code it reads:

```
Plot[x^2, {x, -3, 3},PlotLabels -> "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)]\)"]
```

The result is a weirdly placed label that looks broken (Mathematica 11.3 on macOS).
I lost some times to figure out what was the problem and it turns out it was the superscript: by writing the input "by hand" as `"\!\(x\^2\)"` everything works nicely.
See this picture to understand what I mean.
[image: PlotLabels strange behaviour]
Now, my question is: have I always done something fundamentally wrong by using superscript notation inside quotation marks for my labels?
Is this a bug of PlotLabels?

Note that PlotLegends works as expected in both cases:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be a bug. However, I think linear syntax is evil, and would recommend that you avoid it like the plague. Instead, just use an expression:

```
Plot[x^2, {x, -3, 3}, PlotLabels -> x^2]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

*Question*: What is linear syntax?

*Answer*: It is something like "!(x\^2)". This is what happens to a string when you perform 2D formatting inside of a string.

*Question*: Why do you think this is evil?

*Answer*: These are the main reasons:

1. It creates unintelligible code when displayed outside of the Front End (which happens all the time here on MSE).
2. It is extremely difficult to convert into a readable form that can be usefully displayed outside the Front End.
3. It mixes expressions and strings in a hidden way.

Something like:

```
"\!\(x\^2\) vs x"
```

is basically equivalent to:

```
StringForm["`` vs x", HoldForm[x^2]]
```

*(It's a bit more complicated, but this gives the gist)*. The `x^2` part is an expression, while the `x` part is a string. Now, Mathematica has the option [`SingleLetterItalics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SingleLetterItalics), which controls the font slant of single letter "symbols". So, in the following, notice that the `x` in `x^2` gets italicized, while the string `x` does not:

```
Style["\!\(x\^2\) vs x", SingleLetterItalics->True]
```

[image]

This hidden difference between symbols and strings causes endless confusion for people who use linear syntax in plots, where labels are by default displayed in [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm), which has the option [`SingleLetterItalics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SingleLetterItalics) set to [`True`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/True).

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
What do you mean by "linear syntax is evil"?
Anyways, now I notice that even my second plot has a weird spacing between the leader and the text! 
Do you think I should file a bug report?

Comment: @justmyfault See update

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will probably resort to using HoldForm as much as possible!